# jQuery - not operator does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the `not` operator in jQuery work. It is not at all working.

The hover should work on container `ca` but it should not work on its child container `noHover`

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qsLg1ry5/1/)

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="ca" style="height:40%">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <span class="hoverEffect">Some Image</span>
        <span class="noHover">NH</span>
    </div>
    <div class="showContainer">
        <span>New Image</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ca').not('.noHover').hover(function () {
    $('.imageContainer', this).hide();
    $('.showContainer', this).show();

}, function () {
    $('.imageContainer', this).show();
    $('.showContainer', this).hide();
});
```

Comment: "not working" is useless. You need to explain what you wanted the code to do, and what it is doing that you don't want (or what it is not doing that you do want). Did you want to target `.hoverEffect`?

Comment: Do you want this - http://jsfiddle.net/qsLg1ry5/5/

Comment: @Amadan updated the question

Comment: @MohammadAdil, it causing a flicker. But close enough for me to try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different selectors and contexts:

```
$('.ca span:not(.noHover)').hover(function () {
    $('.imageContainer', $(this).closest('.ca')).hide();
    $('.showContainer', $(this).closest('.ca')).show();

}, function () {
    $('.imageContainer', $(this).closest('.ca')).show();
    $('.showContainer', $(this).closest('.ca')).hide();
});
```

Considering the question update, you might want a different selector for the elements to attach the handler to:

```
'.ca, .ca *:not(.noHover)'
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `not` remove elements from the set of matched elements. `.noHover` is not the set of matched element of `$('.ca')`. You can do it like following.

```
$('.ca').hover(function (e) {
    if(e.target.className=='hoverEffect'){
        $('.imageContainer', this).hide();
        $('.showContainer', this).show();
    }    
}, function () {
        $('.imageContainer', this).show();
        $('.showContainer', this).hide();
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsLg1ry5/6/